# OpenLayers 3 GML dimensions

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wfs, gml

I'm using OpenLayers 3.16 and trying to parse the GML I'm getting from a WFS source. It's parsing ok, well mostly, but OL is assuming it's in 2 dimensions, while actually it's in 3. Is there a way to force OL to read it in 3 dimensions?

Comment: Can you show your GML? dimension should be taken into account.

Comment: There should be no need to force anything if OL 3 supports three dimensions. If GML is correct the dimensions are given in the data and OL 3 has all the information that is needed for parsing.

Comment: It's not saying anywhere in the GML how many dimensions it has, I have no way of editing this in the service as far as I know...
Also here's a pastebin with an example: http://pastebin.com/JBYxcjjq